# Appcelerator SDK - Where to save download and retrive it after app update?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

i have a problem with appcelerator SDK and the storage of files.

If i download a file ( PDF ) and i save it local,

if i release a new version of the app i'm unable to read the previous downloaded file.

how can i solve this? where i need to save the files

now i'm saving it in the app data directory

i retrive the directory with 

`Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory)`

is possibile that? or i need to download all files every time i upgrade my app?

Comment: Is this happening for iOS/Android or both. Which version of the SDK are you using. Did you confirm that the PDF is getting downloaded correctly.

Comment: in ios and yes pdf is saved correctly ( sdk 5.0.0)

Comment: can you share a code sample? Usually it works.

Comment: It looks like you've found a bug. The file should remain accessible after updating an app as long as the app ID remains the same. Please check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Comment: Could you get any solution to this? If you have created a JIRA ticket, then please share it here in the community so that we too can track its updates.